# PictureMarkerSymbol is not working properly

Tags: javascript, arcgis

Here I am using ArcGIS javascript library. I'm adding blinking dot on map. So I'm using PictureMarkerSymbol to create graphic On Map, But it is working as unexpectedly.

Here is the code which I'm using to create graphic on map:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>

     <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/"></script>

    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/geometry/Point",
        "esri/Basemap"
      ], function(
        Map,
        MapView,
        Graphic,
        Point,
        Basemap
      ) {
        var map = new Map({
          basemap: "dark-gray"
        });

        var view = new MapView({
          center: [-80, 35],
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
          zoom: 5,
        });

        let point =  new Point({
          latitude: "42.07611900",
          longitude: "-71.42270700"
        });

        // Create a graphic and add the geometry and symbol to it
        var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: point,
          symbol: {
            type: "picture-marker", // autocasts as new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
            url: "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/115303/screenshots/1367782/loading.gif",
            width: "50px",
            height: "50px"
          }
        });

        view.graphics.add(pointGraphic);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I'm executing above code then it showing me black dot on map.

Here is the image which I'm trying to show on map with animation.

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/115303/screenshots/1367782/loading.gif

But below is the output of the code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 Your code working fine. but your symbol url 
 "http://cdn.dribbble.com/users/115303/screenshots/1367782/loading.gif" is not 
 supported. kindly change your symbol url and check. 

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>

     <link rel="stylesheet" 
         href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/esri/themes/light/main.css"
       />
  </head>

   <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>

    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/"></script>

<style>
  html,
  body,
  #viewDiv {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<script>
  require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/Graphic",
    "esri/geometry/Point",
    "esri/Basemap"
  ], function(
    Map,
    MapView,
    Graphic,
    Point,
    Basemap
  ) {
    var map = new Map({
      basemap: "dark-gray"
    });

    var view = new MapView({
      center: [-80, 35],
      container: "viewDiv",
      map: map,
      zoom: 5,
    });

    let point =  new Point({
      latitude: "42.07611900",
      longitude: "-71.42270700"
    });

    // Create a graphic and add the geometry and symbol to it
    var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
      geometry: point,
      symbol: {
        type: "picture-marker", // autocasts as new PictureMarkerSymbol()
        url: "https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/images/bluepin.png", 
        width: "25px",
        height: "25px"
      }
    });

    view.graphics.add(pointGraphic);
  });
   </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

[image]

Comment: -static image is working fine but animated image (gif, svg) are not working.

Comment: ActualIy I'm using svg image here, I have just show gif image to tell animated images are not working. I have already told i just want to show blinking point here.

Answer (score 1):

From the [esri documentation on PictureMarkerSymbols](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-symbols-PictureMarkerSymbol.html)

> **Known Limitations**:
>
> - Rendering SVG paths as images is not supported in IE11.
> - **Animated gif/png images are not supported**. See the [Custom WebGL layer view](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/custom-gl-visuals/index.html) sample to learn how to accomplish this using WebGL.

The [sample code sandbox](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=custom-gl-visuals) gives a demonstration of what you're looking to do.